# Как вернуть String из getComputedStyle?

Tags: javascript, строки

Вопрос, собственно, заключается в названии: как вернуть `String` из `getComputedStyle`?

Comment: какую строку Вы хотите вернуть?

Comment: @Дмытрык строку со значением, очевидно

Comment: Ну то есть какого-то конкретного элемента, например marginTop

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Ну ссылка это здорово, но это не ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var style = getComputedStyle(elem);
var d =style.marginTop;
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что console.log выводит, а в переменную записать нельзя

Comment: изменил ответ, так работает?

Comment: Работает, большое спасибо